# Odd use of determinants in a product related to a problem of analytical geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

This is from R.M.Khan's Analytical Geometry:

[image: From R.M.Khan's Analytical Geometry]

Why did the author consider using the determinant in such particular way?

And what is the product this is referring to? It is not the usual matrix multiplication.

Can someone name the concepts used by the writer?

Comment: The first matrix is multiplied by the transpose of the second one. Why he writes things this way escapes me.

Comment: @mlc but it's not matrix multiplication. So, is such kind of multiplication even possible ?

Comment: If mlc is right, it *is* matrix multiplication – there has simply been a typographical error, where a "$t$" has been left off the 2nd matrix, so you don't see that you're meant to take the transpose.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How it is a transpose there is no $0$ in the second matrix

Comment: I didn't say the 2nd matrix is the transpose of the first. I said that what has been written as the product of matrices $A$ and $B$ was supposed to be written as the product of $a$ and $B$-transpose, but the "transpose" got left out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the use of 0 in the first matrix is this just an trial and error attempt on the authors part to make the equation this way or some form of problem solving tactic.

Comment: I know why determinant is used here.I am going to post an answer for this.

Comment: @mlc these aren't matrices, these are determinants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author has considered the product :

$\begin{vmatrix} 2l_{ 1 }l_{ 2 } & { l_{ 1 }m_{ 2 }+l_{ 2 }m_{ 1 } } & l_{ 1 }n_{ 2 }+l_{ 2 }n_{ 1 } \\ l_{ 1 }m_{ 2 }+l_{ 2 }m_{ 1 } & 2m_{ 1 }m_{ 2 } & m_{ 1 }n_{ 2 }+m_{ 2 }n_{ 1 } \\ l_{ 1 }n_{ 2 }+l_{ 2 }n_{ 1 } & m_{ 1 }n_{ 2 }+m_{ 2 }n_{ 1 } & 2n_{ 1 }n_{ 2 } \end{vmatrix}$ (Let us name it $D$)

$= \begin{vmatrix} l_ 1 & l_2 & 0 \\ m_1 & m_2 & 0 \\ n_1 & n_2 & 0 \end{vmatrix}$ $(D_1)$ $\times$ $\begin{vmatrix} l_{ 2} & l_{ 1 } & 1 \\ m_{ 2 } & m_{ 1 } & 1 \\ n_{ 2 } & n_{ 1 } & 1 \end{vmatrix}$ $(D_2)$

Just in order to prove the condition required.

Here $0$ is used in first determinant to make the product equal to required condition determinant.No other concept.Just mathematical adjustment.

If some variables $a,b,c,f,g,h$

Satisfy the condition :

$l_1l_2=a , l_1m_2+l_2m_1=2h , m_1m_2=b , l_1n_2+l_2n_1=2g, m_1n_2+m_2n_1=2f,n_1n_2=c$

for two st.lines $l_1x+m_1y+n_1$ and $l_2x+m_2y+n_2$.

Then the equation :

$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

must represent a pair of st. lines.

Or viceversa, If the equation $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ represents a pair of st. line than $a,b,c,f,g,h$ must satisfy

$\begin{vmatrix} a & h & g \\ h & b & f \\ g & f & c \end{vmatrix}=0$

Beacuse, since they represent pair of st. lines , they must satisfy

$l_1l_2=a , l_1m_2+l_2m_1=2h , m_1m_2=b , l_1n_2+l_2n_1=2g, m_1n_2+m_2n_1=2f,n_1n_2=c$

for two st.lines $l_1x+m_1y+n_1$ and $l_2x+m_2y+n_2$.

and the determinant  $D$ can be written as $D_1 \times D_2$

Where $|D_1|=0$ . Hence $|D|$ also must be $=0$

**P.S.** : Someone might think that first determinant is multiplied to transpose of second determinant.No.There are several ways to multiply two determinants.Namely :

- Row by Row
- Column by Row
- Row by Column
- Column by Column

The result is basically the same in all.

Since, in matrix multiplication, we can use only Row by Column procedure, and many people use the same in determinant multiplication too this multiplication of determinants seems to be weird.So, there is nothing wrong or weird here as, may be, the author of this book has practice to multiply determinants Row by Row.

Comment: Both the matrix in multiplication is same or you just made a typo with not entering 0 in the first matrix.

Comment: The authors ideas was to show that (ahg...gfc) is a necessary condition for second degree non homogeneous equation to represent a pair of straight lines. Your answer is taking it as a prerequisite.

Comment: If you check the matrix multiplication which you are using in your solution it's not equal with the left hand side matrix

Comment: @WRI Wait.I a resolving that matter in the new edit.

Comment: The problem, imo, is the book (article) shown in the question makes a rather weird, and for me incomprehensible, use of determinant-like symbols and some kind of product which I just can't understand, and I'm not sure this answer addresses those problems. The most annoying part is that a reader **shouldn't** be dealing with this nonsense: this should either be widely standard and well known stuff *or else* it should be clearly and exactly defined in the text.

Comment: @WRI I think it should be okay now.

Comment: @JaideepKhare mathematical adjustment. That just settled me. Anyway thanks for your time. I am grateful to you !

Comment: @JaideepKhare The author used the transpose of D2. It's just that D1 x D2 does not provide D. But D1 x D2' does. This is the most weird **mathematical adjustment** I have ever seen.

Comment: @WRI Read my new edit (in the last).There you will get answer for that weirdness.

Comment: @JaideepKhare  Seriously???? I have never known that. I need some reference to verify. Can you provide any? I am having a difficult time finding sources to be assured.

Comment: @WRI Yes! Check out this link. http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/matrices-and-determinants/operations-on-determinants.aspx

Comment: @JaideepKhare May be I didn't read determinants well. Thank you!! I found it in a good way in my linear algebra textbook.

Comment: @How have they proved?I simply knew this fact.I don't know exact proof of this property of determinants.If you have found than please give me idea behind procedure, or suggest me an edit to this solution and send a photo, I will read it.

Comment: @WRI I forgot to tag you, read my previous comment.

Comment: @JaideepKhare Sorry but I didn't find the proof too. Just the statement.